# How to retrieve value from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using a Java script variable

```
var parameter = $(this).find('#[id$=hfUrl]').val();
```

This value return to parameter now

```
"{'objType':'100','objID':'226','prevVoting':'"   // THIS VALUE RETURN BY
```

$(this).find('[$id=hfurl]').val();

I want to store objType value in new:

```
 var OBJECTTYPE = //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE so OBJECTTYPE contain 400
```

I am trying

```
OBJECTTYPE = parameter.objType; // but it's not working...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that `parameter` contains this value? First, the object is malformed (but maybe you just forgot a `'`) and second, it seems unlikely to me that `.find('[$id=hfurl]')` returns such an object (if you are using jQuery). Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: I HAVE EDITED MY QUESTION NOW CHECK OUT...

Comment: `"{'objType':'100','objID':'226','prevVoting':'"` is still not correct syntax. What about errors? `$(this).find('[$id=hfurl]')` likely returns a jQuery object. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT ACTUALLY I AM STORING {'objType':'100','objID':'226','prevVoting':' IN HIDDEN FIELD VALUE  AND ON CLIENT SIDE I AM RETRIVING IT THATS ALL...

Comment: It would help us very much, if you'd answer my questions: **Are you getting errors on the console?** and **Are you using jQuery?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `parameter['objType']`.

Just a note: your code snippet doesn't look right, but I guess you just posted it wrong.

Comment: Assuming everything else is correct, if `parameter['objType']` works, then `parameter.objType` should work too.

Comment: Your updated code changes things a bit :) Felix has just posted a perfect answer to you question, then

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure if I am correct but lets see:

You say you are storing `{'objType':'100','objID':'226','prevVoting':'` as string in a hidden field. The string is not a correct JSON string. It should look like this:

```
{"objType":100,"objID":226,"prevVoting":""}
```

You have to use double-quotes for strings inside a JSON object. For more information, see http://json.org/

Now, I think with `$(this).find('[$id=hfurl]');` you want to retrieve that value. It looks like you are trying to find an element with ID `hfurl`,but `$id` is not a valid HTML attribute. This seems like very wrong jQuery to me. Try this instead:

```
var parameter = $('#hfurl').val();
```

`parameter` will contain a JSON string, so you have to [parse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) it before you can access the values:

```
parameter = $.parseJSON(parameter);
```

Then you should be able to access the data with `parameter.objType`.

**Update:**

I would not store "broken" JSON in the field. Store the string similar to the one I shoed above and if you want to add values you can do it **after** parsing like so:

```
parameter.vote = vote;
parameter.myvote = vote;
```

It is less error prone.

Comment: actually u r correct "{'objType':'100','objID':'226','prevVoting':'" what i am doing here am adding some another value to it like parameter++ vote + "','myvote':'" + vote + "'}",

Comment: @Nishant: Ok, that does not matter, but the strings *inside* the object must be enclosed in double-quotes. Could you please edit your question and add the corresponding line where you are adding the other string?